# What happens when a Django table hits max on an ID/PK column?

Tags: django, django-database

Lets imagine that you have an application where an specific table has A LOT new objects (in Django terms) created. Nevermind how many are deleted, but let's say it is sufficient to keep the table functional.

After quite a while, how unlikely it may ever be, the table hits max on the ID/PK column. What happens next? How does Django handle that situation?

Comment: Did you try it? Doesn't seem hard to give it a go.

Comment: Not yet. Wanted to hear if anyone had any experiences on it before venturing there.

Comment: For postgres you can set the id of an object to 2147483647 and then try and add one more.

Comment: Django does not handle this. What happens depends on your database.

Comment: @allcaps I thought postgresql used bigserial for ids, but I guess it makes sense to use serial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to set an id of 2147483648 with a Postgres database. Django raises `DataError: integer out of range`. If I try the same in Postgres I get `[22003] ERROR: integer out of range`. So it looks like Django just throws the db error.

If I search the Django source code for DataError I find: 
https://github.com/django/django/blob/3c447b108ac70757001171f7a4791f493880bf5b/django/db/utils.py#L53 which confirms that Django re-throws backend-specific database exceptions.

You can always define the primary key field yourself and mark it as primary:

```
 id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

This will increase id's form 2147483647 to 9223372036854775807.

If that isn't enough switch to uuid:

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#bigintegerfield and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield

Comment: Note that 1.10 added a [`BigAutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield) -- in case you want to keep the auto-incrementing behaviour.

Comment: This answer is awesome. It also shows that it is possible to migrate out of the problem if it should ever occur. I knew that I could set the foreign key to my own data type. the point of asking this question, was that I didn't really know how the error would display it self, and i couldn't find anything by searching.